# Как пройтись по массиву и записать содержимое второго элемента в переменную?

Tags: python, массивы

Имеется массив из нескольких элементов,один из элементов принимает null значение(то есть внутри ничего нет), а вот второй и последующий имеют - какое-то содержимое, вопрос - как обратится ко второму элементу(который содержит данные) и записать содержимое в переменную?Чтобы потом можно было записать в ново созданную форму - если нужно могу чуть подробнее объяснить что это за форма.

Собственно сам массив

texture.longName ##

и содержимое

```
(1)  * longName : &lt;None&gt;
(2)  * longName : objects\pc\lm\mesh\lmcl_cash_koreandress09_body.dds
(3)  * longName : objects\pc\lm\mesh\lmcl_cash_koreandress07_head.dds
```

texture это своего рода контейнер данных, из файла,а для обращение к конкретным данным просто указывается, название нужного элемента( в моем случае это longName).
Но к примеру там еще есть

```
* type : ENVIRONMENT
```

и если указать texture.type - то выведет ENVIRONMENT, это я к тому чтобы не возникало вопросов - что это за массив такой! Я просто не очень силен в питоне, и не пойму как получить значение именно второго элемента в переменную, надеюсь кто-нибудь объяснит!

Comment: Про то, как адресовать второй элемент в списке вам уже ответили, если вы решаете какую-то другую задачу, то её нужно обрисовать в вопросе. Из ваших комментариев к ответу Игоря не ясно для чего нужно проверять на None именно этот второй элемент, если по задаче он и последующие не None, и как вы хотите формировать форму тоже не ясно.

Comment: @idlesign , Эм тут оказывается проблема в моем незнании питона, ибо я не как не могу понять, почему цикл помешает элементы - в форму `daeImage.initFrom`, по очереди, то есть не из массива, а по одному, вот как идет [null],[object],[object1] - так он и добавляет С начало Null в форму, потом цикл повторяется и в форму уже помешается object, смыл в том что null,object,object1, изначально не помешаются в массив, а берутся как есть из исходных данных по одному Проще говоря, доступа к первому полюбому нету(после обращения) Может мне приложить больше исходного кода Ибо не как не пойму как это обойти.

Comment: К сожалению, после вашего комментария задача яснее не стала. Да, возможно, следует приложить код, но что нужно сделать точно — это показать, что у вас уже есть (исходные данные + ваши наработки по решению задачи), и *сформулировать*, что вы желаете получить на выходе.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/kSmhKkfA я правда не знаю чем вам это поможет, ибо сейчас обращение - texture.longName[0:1], выводит мне первую букву строки(причем как для первой строки _cash_koreandress09_body, так и для второй _cash_koreandress07_head, то есть оно обрабатывает как строки, а не как объекты), а мне надо чтобы выводило первую строку со всем содержимым( то есть _cash_koreandress07_head), питон просто ужас...

Comment: Не увидел по ссылке ни texture, ни initForm. Первую букву выводит потому что вы его просите об этом: texture.longName[0:1] — здесь сказано взять символ с позиции 0 до позиции 1, то есть первую букву. Если вам нужна строка целиком, обращайтесь прямо к texture.longName.

Answer (score 1):

Обращайтесь так:

```
texture.longName[1]
```

В Python для индексирования массива используются квадратные скобки `[]`,
нумерация начинается с 0, стало быть, второй элемент имеет индекс 1.

**Обновление 1**

Проверить, является ли первый (то есть нулевой) элемент равным `None`:

```
if texture.longName[0] is None:
  # doing something
```

Проверить, является ли массив равным `None` (в этом случае, это, конечно, уже не массив, а `None`):

```
if texture.longName is None:
  # doing something
```

Проверить, есть ли первый (то есть, нулевой) элемент в массиве или элемента нет (то есть, массив пуст):

```
if len( texture.longName ) > 0:
  # doing something
```

** Обновление 2 **

Если ваши данные представлены не в виде массива, а в виде строки,
содержащей элементы разделённый запятой или каким-то другим образом,
то вы можете разбить строку на список элементов с помощью операции `split`.

```
  my_str.split(',')
```

Если разбиение осуществляется более сложным образом, а не просто запятой,
то вам могут пригодиться регулярные выражения (модуль `re`) и функции `re.split` и `re.find`.

Comment: #А где следует начать проверку - если элемент is None ?# ## До обращения к записи в новую форму -таким образом  ##                           `texName = texture.longName if texName is None: texName = texture.longName[1]`, или при обращении `daeImage.initFrom = texture.longName if daeImage.initFrom is None: daeImage.initFrom = texture.longName[1] `  ? Или я что-то еще упускаю ?

Comment: видимо проблема именно в обращении к массиву в проверке,если обратится таким образом  `if texName is None:` , то он пройдет по всем элементам, и естественно будет Не None, а вот как следует обратится именно для первого элемента, ` if texName[1]` - не работает, если объявлять как переменную ` texRname2 = texture.longName[0]` то тоже не работает ? Как быть ?

Comment: @LightFusion: Добавил вам ещё обновление на тему того как проверить первый элемент/массив на равенство `None`

Comment: проблема оказывается в том что массив texture.LongName, принимает содержимое всех элементов как цельную строку(и поэтому при обращении к элементу получаю ошибку - Out of range error), я правда не очень понимаю как при этом DaeImage.Inifrom понимает откуда ее начать разделять, нудаладно, на сколько я понял нужно чуть раньше менять(когда еще сам массив заполняется)

Comment: @LightFusion: Смотрите ещё одно обновление